# How do I catch GotError [HTTPError]: Response code 404 (Not Found) in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-error, node.js-got

Assuming that the url provided is wrong, the Got module raises a HTTPError, how do I catch the error? Try catch doesn't work

```js
const got = require('got');
got(`https://www.wrongurl.com`)
                .then(response => {
                    //do stuff
                })
```

Comment: `.catch(() => { ... })`?!

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
got(...).then(
  response => { /* handle good response here */}, 
  error => { /* handle error here */ }
)
```

Simple `.catch(() => { ... })` may catch an error in `.then(response...` part as well, that's not what you expect.

Also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then for reference.